# Loop through objects like box0, box1, box2 with a for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have 5 objects, `box0 box1 box2 box3 box4 box5`.

Is there any way to access their members in a for loop?
I tried this way, but it wouldn't work because `box${i}`is a string

```
 let boxCoordinates: Array<Coordinate> = [];
 for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
         boxCoordinates.push(`box${i}`.current.getBoundingClientRect) //box0, box1, box2, box3, box4
     }
```

Comment: You can't construct a variable name this way. You'll need to have the objects in an array or object to do this.

Comment: Should access them by class, and `document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach...`

Comment: if the `box...` variables are global then you can access them via `window['box'+i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` but note that using this method may has some problems and risk for you: see [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript)

```js
var box0 = {index:1};

for(let i=0;i<1;i++)
   {
       let d = eval(`box${i}`);
       console.log(typeof d);//object
       console.log(d.index) //1
   }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBARg9gHgBggXggbwJYDsAmBTOALgEYBfAbgFgAoGmiAGzwBdp4BhGGMHbEZvAGdCEAIJgwIAJ4AeEFikA%20FBADaAXSrUIO3ToBm3ABRNWGZAnIYZxKwGo7ASnp7daGgEgvpiDhV5QBiMAA1g4ABJMUmDHLS8PAGMYLEEYJgA6BhgAcyNmKQAHPBh9X1iXV1cklLS8TJyjHHTsfDhHCAB6DrCEABo2OGJ%20sIAmYfgAZnG4ABYK11IgA)

Comment: Perhaps also suggest an option that doesn't rely on `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to not have them all tracked in an array in the first place?

```
// Assuming their defined somewhere else
const boxArray = [box1, box2, box3, box4, box5];
for (let i =0; i < boxArray.length; i++ ) { 
  const box = boxArray[i];
  // Do what you need with box now
}
```

Comment: Not really, I just wanted to see if I can do that dynamically.